# Is it safe to visit pages that use WebTorrent javascript technology, like bitchute?

Tags: ip-address

On the Tor project page there is an explicit warning against the use of BitTorrent technology, as this will reveal your own IP address. But websites like bitchute.com use a technology called WebTorrent, a Javascript implementation of BitTorrent.

I am neither an expert on BitTorrent nor WebTorrent, but I suspect that the same IP issue exists at WebTorrent.

If this is the case, do you have any recommendations on this issue? Services like bitchute.com make no secret of the fact that they use WebTorrent in their browser pages. It becomes problematic if such technology is used quietly in the background.

Comment: WebTorrent uses WebRTC, which might leak your local IP address to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** use any sort of torrent within Tor. It is even in the documentation. (See [here](https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea) even though it says BitTorrent,it applies to all torrent)

Also, WebRTC is just plain a privacy risk